# Make cache persist even if Node process dies

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, axios

My backend, Nodejs, has to make some API GET request calls to external services to retrieve data and serve as a webpage. These API calls are being cached. 
Since I'm using Heroku, this data is being removed every time the apps enter to hibernate state. Is there any cache library that persists? Currently I'm using `lru-cache` and `axios-extensions`.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { cacheAdapterEnhancer } = require('axios-extensions');
const LRUCache = require("lru-cache")

const options = {
    defaultCache: new LRUCache({ maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, max: 100 })
}

const http = axios.create({
        headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
        timeout: 60000,
        adapter: cacheAdapterEnhancer(axios.defaults.adapter)
    }
)

getData: async () => {
    try {
        const response = await http.get(url, config)
        const data = response.data
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are caching in memory and your app crash or the server goes down, you will lose your cache, so you need to have a cache DB, like memcached or redis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sounds good! I will check it

Comment: Thanks @giankotarola I finally made it work! That was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can use [persistent-node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/persistent-node-cache) package. It provides the capability to save the cache data on disk if the process/application crashes which can be restored when the application starts again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @giankotarola in comments, I needed to use cache DB to solve the problem. Finally I managed to make it work using Redis! My final code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const redis = require('redis')

// create and connect redis client to local instance.
const client = redis.createClient()

// Print redis errors to the console
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Error " + err)
});

const http = axios.create({
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
    timeout: 60000
}
)

let config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
    }
}

let url = 'https://example.com'

module.exports={
    getData: async () => {
        try {
            // Try to get response from Redis store
            const response = await client.get(url)
            return responseJSON = JSON.parse(response)
        } catch (err) {
            try {
                const response = await http.get(url, config)
                const data = response.data

                // Save response in Redis store
                client.setex(url, 60 * 60 * 1000, JSON.stringify(data));
                return data
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```